# How to associate AD users to their entries with MS Membership Provider?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, active-directory, asp.net-membership

My company has just switch to Active Directory, and I've been converting our legacy apps (mvc, silverlight, asp.net) to authenticate with AD using the asp.net membership provider.

We have an application that users enter and store form entry data which is forever associated with their username which the app gets from 'user.name' from the provider.  The problem is whenever somebody changes their name (marriage, etc), the application has to be updated to change their existing entries to their new last name.

Is there a consistent field in AD that can be gotten to through the asp.net membership provider that can be used to associate with entries?  or a best practice for handling such things?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your ASP.NET applications to authenticate against Active Directory, you need an Active Directory membership provider. See this article for more info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650308.aspx.

Comment: I do currently authenticate against AD which tells me that the user is indeed part of our AD environment, and the built in provider gives me the user name as part of the 'user.cs' class.  What happens is that occasionally users change their name, so the records that I have created that are associated based on their user name have to be updated in the database.  I'm curious what the best practice (or just a good way) to associate a database entry with a AD user (ad\username), so that I can still find records created by them after a name change (ad\changedName)

Comment: @MongooseNX, which Membership provider does your application have configured in web.config? If you have written your own provider, does it access both the AD and ASP.NET membership tables?

Comment: I'm using System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider, and it only accesses AD.

Comment: If you want your membership provider to do more work than it does "out of the box" or to work differently, you need to roll your own, using the current one as a base class if it permits it and it provides you with a useful starting point. This video may help: http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/how-do-i/how-do-i-create-a-custom-membership-provider

Comment: AD provides an API in System.DirectoryServices.Directory entry that looks capable of updating the user's name. You could look at extending the MembershipUser class to include a property for the user's name which is propagated to their AD directory entry. Worth considering whether it is worth the effort if this use case only happens occasionally.